# C++ Insertion sort confusion

Tags: c++, algorithm, insertion-sort

I'm trying to implement insertion sort on my own in C++. I know there are plenty of examples and I compared my solution with existing ones and don't see why mine isn't working. I know there are libraries for this but I want to implement it on my own. I've got 2 different implementations as shown below (**A** - one that works, **B** - one that doesn't work).

Here is **A** - One that does work. Nothing new here.

```
    int myArr[5] = {5,4,3,2,1};

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++){

        int j = i - 1;
        int key = myArr[i];

        while(myArr[j] > key && j >= 0){
            myArr[j + 1] = myArr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }        
        myArr[j + 1] = key;

        //Printing array to see what changed:
        for (size_t k = 0; k < 5; ++k){
            cout << myArr[k] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
   }
```

Sample output from **A**:

```
    4 5 3 2 1 
    3 4 5 2 1 
    2 3 4 5 1 
    1 2 3 4 5
```

Here is **B**, something I came up with. **B** is very similar to **A** except for the lines I've pointed out, where I chose to use myArr subscript instead of key:

```
    int myArr[5] = {5,4,3,2,1};

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++){

        int j = i - 1;
        //int key = myArr[i]; //DIFFERENT FROM **A**


        //************** DIFFERENT FROM A **************
        //I didn't use "key", instead I chose to use myArr[i]
        while(myArr[j] > myArr[i] && j >= 0){
            myArr[j + 1] = myArr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }

        //************** DIFFERENT FROM A **************
        //Same here: I use myArr[i] instead of key        
        myArr[j + 1] = myArr[i];

        //Printing array to see what changed:
        for (size_t k = 0; k < 5; ++k){
            cout << myArr[k] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
   }
```

Sample output from **B**:

```
    5 5 3 2 1 
    5 5 5 2 1 
    5 5 5 5 1 
    5 5 5 5 5
```

I don't understand, the only thing I changed was not storing the current value in a variable. I know I can easily do that and all will be well but what bothers me is that I don't know why **B** is incorrect. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You changed from **A** which is a correct rendition of an insertion sort using a `while` loop to **B** which isn't. `key` is key. Nit, you can save a comparison in `while(myArr[j] > key && j >= 0)` by changing the order to `while(j >= 0 && myArr[j] > key)` so when `j == 0` the second comparison is never made. And, ... if you haven't read [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), it is well worth a read by all.

Comment: I'm not your downvoter. Most likely it is due to someone who considers the question one that could be solved with a bit more debugging. But sometimes I swear is it just a "phase of the moon" thing. Don't sweat the downvote, they come out in the wash... (I didn't elaborate further on `key` is key, as ggorlen had already posted the answer by then)

Comment: Saw your explanation and deleted my comment. Thanks for the debug link.

Comment: I rarely ever downvote as a matter of policy. I if do downvote, I leave a comment that "I am downvoting because ...". Unless the downvoter has the integrity to leave a comment (few do), then it serves no purpose (other than apparently making them feel better) and provides no meaningful help to the person who came here looking for help to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good exercise in walking through the code by hand. What's changed? `key` is temporary storage for the value at `myArr[i]`. The problem with the seemingly innocuous refactor is the fact that `myArr[j + 1]` *is* `myArr[i]` on the first iteration of the inner loop. Notice:

```
int j = i - 1;
...
myArr[j + 1] = myArr[j]; // j + 1 === i
```

which is essentially:

```
myArr[i] = myArr[j]; // whoops!
```

Here, we've reassigned `myArr[i]` to something else instead of copying and storing the value in `key`. We're losing one element on every outer loop iteration whenever the `myArr[i]` element isn't already sorted.

Keep the `key` variable!

Answer (score 0):

I will use i = 1 to show why it is working different from what you expect.

```
int j = i - 1;
```

j becomes 0.

```
myArr[j + 1] = myArr[j];
```

Here myArr[1] is assigned value of myArr[0]. This is where the problem lies, as

```
myArr[j + 1] = myArr[i];
```

assigns value of myArr[0] (modified in previously mentioned line) to myArr[1].

In short, the shifting erases the value to be inserted. That's why you need to copy it to another variable (key in code A).